# Java 7 default locale

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, locale, java-7

I have just installed jre7 and I'm surprised to see that my default locale is now en_US. With jre6 it was de_CH.

What is different with jre7? Is the default locale no more the one of the Operating System? (btw, I'm using Windows7)

Thx for your answer.

Edit:
I have seen the Locale for **Category.FORMAT** is the "old" one (de_CH). The Locale for **Category.DISPLAY** takes the language from the language of the OS (in Windows this is done in Control Panel > Region and Language > Keyboard and Languages > Display Language) and the contry from...?

What seems to be different is the property "**user.country**". With Java6 I get "CH" and with Java7 I get "US".

Comment: There must be some error. Did you try a simple test app? I'd reinstall it.

Comment: I set a breakpoint just after having started the app and the default locale is en_US. For all persons in my company is the same

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is as designed.  Java 7 has changed the way `Locale.getDefault()` works.  A defect has been entered with Oracle, but they basically said this is As Designed.

To sum up, you must modify the Display Language of the OS.  Modifying the Region Format only is no longer sufficient.

Read the bug report here: [Locale.getDefault() returns wrong Locale for Java SE 7](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7073906)

Comment: According to the bug report, this "Feature" was fixed in Java 8 build 04. So in Java 8, we can expect the correct behavior.

Comment: @dARKpRINCE [The fix](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7073906) was actually also backported to 7u4: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-2217027

Comment: I'm not sure what the fix is, I've tried Locale.getDefault() on both the latest release of JDK 7 and latest JDK 8 beta and both return a different result than JDK <= 6

Comment: Is this still a valid answer? I guess they've reverted the feature with Java 8.

Comment: Should't it work correctly with Locale.getDefault(Category.FORMAT)?

Answer (score 16):

The change is described quite well in this [blog post](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20141015235927/http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2011/12/default-locale-changes-in-java-7.html) and on the [compatibility page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html).

Note that you can revert to the old behavior by setting the `sun.locale.formatasdefault` system property to `true`.

Comment: blog... The Wayback Machine has not archived that URL

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be some changes regarding Locale in Java 7, namely differentiation between UI and 'user' locale. See [this](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/#fa538265). There is [now](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale.Category,%20java.util.Locale%29) `setDefault(Locale.Category, Locale)`. However, this does not really explain what you are experiencing - I'm merely pointing out the fact that there has been changes in Java 7 regarding locale handling.

Answer (score 2):

This really looks like a bug to me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

System.err.println(Locale.getDefault());
}
```

running this with java 5 or java 6 prints: 'nl_NL'
java7: 'en_US'

Comment: What about Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.DISPLAY) and Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT) ? Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

What about setting your Locale at the start of the program in the following way, depending on java version:

```
public class LocaleFormatter {

private static Locale locale;

private LocaleFormatter() {

}

public static Locale setDefaultLocale() {
    if (locale == null) {
        if (!System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.7.")) {
            locale = Locale.getDefault();
        } else {
            try {
                Class localeClass = Class.forName("java.util.Locale");
                Class categoryClass = Class.forName("java.util.Locale$Category");
                Object format = null;
                for (Object constant : categoryClass.getEnumConstants()) {
                    if (constant.toString().equals("FORMAT")) {
                        format = constant;
                    }
                }
                Method method = localeClass.getMethod("getDefault", categoryClass);

                locale = (Locale) method.invoke(Locale.getDefault(), format);
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return locale;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting "Location" in Windows control panel Regional and language options (German: "Region und Sprache", "Aufenthaltsort").

Answer (score 0):

If you are brave enough you can call the :

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.getDefault());
```

This sets the default Locale for both of those categories

```
public static synchronized void setDefault(Locale newLocale) {
   setDefault(Category.DISPLAY, newLocale);
   setDefault(Category.FORMAT, newLocale);
   defaultLocale = newLocale;
}
```

But this of course could cause side effects.