# How do I set the default locale in the JVM?

Tags: java, localization, globalization

I want to set the default `Locale` for my JVM to `fr_CA`. What are the possible options to do this?

I know of only one option `Locale.setDefault()`

Comment: Beware of [Java 7 default locale changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107972/java-7-default-locale).

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings

Answer (score 180, accepted):

From the [Oracle Reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using):

> The default locale of your application is determined in three ways.
>   First, unless you have explicitly changed the default, the
>   [`Locale.getDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29) method returns the locale that was initially determined
>   by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when it first loaded. That is, the
>   JVM determines the default locale from the host environment. The host
>   environment's locale is determined by the host operating system and
>   the user preferences established on that system.
>
> Second, on some Java runtime implementations, the application user can
>   override the host's default locale by providing this information on
>   the command line by setting the `user.language`, `user.country`, and
>   `user.variant` system properties.
>
> Third, your application can call the [`Locale.setDefault(Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29)
>   method. The setDefault(Locale aLocale) method lets your application
>   set a systemwide *(actually VM-wide)* resource. After you set the default locale with this
>   method, subsequent calls to Locale.getDefault() will return the newly
>   set locale.

Comment: is their any conflict while fetching the same locale from ResourceBundle. I tried to fetch the bundle but i got what i had initially

Answer (score 189):

You can set it on the command line via JVM parameters:

```
java -Duser.country=CA -Duser.language=fr ... com.x.Main
```

For further information look at [*Internationalization: Understanding Locale in the Java Platform - Using Locale*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using)

Comment: You can also set it via the _JAVA_OPTIONS environment variable.

Comment: Via [Java 7 default locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107972/java-7-default-locale):
`setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault=true /m`

Comment: Depending on your usecase and your JDK Version you can also try to use:
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS (which seems to work on most JVMs)
IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS (only working with IBM JVMs where _JAVA_OPTIONS has no effect) 
JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS (since JDK 9+, see stackoverflow.com/q/52986487/537554)

Answer (score 56):

In the answers here, up to now, we find two ways of changing the JRE locale setting:

- Programatically, using [Locale.setDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault(java.util.Locale)) (which, in my case, was the solution, since I didn't want to require any action of the user):

  ```
  Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
  ```
- Via arguments to the JVM:

  ```
  java -jar anApp.jar -Duser.language=pt-BR
  ```

But, just as reference, I want to note that, on Windows, there is one more way of changing the locale used by the JRE, as documented [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml): changing the system-wide language.

> **Note**: You must be logged in with an account that has Administrative Privileges.
>
> 1. Click **Start > Control Panel**.
> 2. Windows 7 and Vista: Click Clock, Language and Region > **Region and Language**.
>
>    Windows XP: Double click the **Regional and Language Options**
>      icon.
>
>    The **Regional and Language Options** dialog box appears.
> 3. Windows 7: Click the **Administrative** tab.
>
>    Windows XP and Vista: Click the **Advanced** tab.
>
>    (If there is no Advanced tab, then you are not logged in with
>      administrative privileges.)
> 4. Under the **Language for non-Unicode programs** section, select the desired language from the drop down menu.
> 5. Click **OK**.
>
>    The system displays a dialog box asking whether to use existing
>      files or to install from the operating system CD. Ensure that you have
>      the CD ready.
> 6. Follow the guided instructions to install the files.
> 7. Restart the computer after the installation is complete.

Certainly on Linux the JRE also uses the system settings to determine which locale to use, but the instructions to set the system-wide language change from distro to distro.

Comment: while this information maybe helpful, I would like to highlight that these steps are different of each OS and for each OS, you may be able to setup a Locale which is used system wide. Java is designed to use that locale as the default locale whenever we are not explicitly setting a default locale. So the information in this answer is about how to set default locale in windows and not in java.

Answer (score 52):

You can use JVM args

```
java -Duser.country=ES -Duser.language=es -Duser.variant=Traditional_WIN
```

Answer (score 23):

If you don't want to change the system's regional settings but only those of the JVM, there is another method to achieve this. You can set a system (or user) environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`. The JVM reads this variable as its startup parameters during initialization. So, if you want to set the *en-US* locale, you just need to set the value of this environment variable to `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US`. Please note the use of spaces to separate multiple options.

Comment: Thank you a million times! I have been searching this for over an hour now. And I finaly find the solution to all my problems here. With 19 Points near the end of the answers.
To make it clear:
How to permanently set the default language for java jdk?
This is the solution!

Comment: One small remark: maybe it's better to set the language to "en" instead of "en-US", at least Oracle SQL Developer had problems with en-US.

Comment: Is it not `en_US` with an underscore rather than a dash?

Comment: @kriegaex I have updated the answer, thanks to raudi's comment.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this:

[image]

[image]

And to capture locale. You can do this:

```
private static final String LOCALE = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getLanguage()
            + "-" + LocaleContextHolder.getLocale().getCountry();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce VM arguments for a `JAR` file with the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JVMArgumentEnforcer
{
    private String argument;

    public JVMArgumentEnforcer(String argument)
    {
        this.argument = argument;
    }

    public static long getTotalPhysicalMemory()
    {
        com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean bean =
                (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)
                        java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
        return bean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize();
    }

    public static boolean isUsing64BitJavaInstallation()
    {
        String bitVersion = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");

        return bitVersion.equals("64");
    }

    private boolean hasTargetArgument()
    {
        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        List<String> inputArguments = runtimeMXBean.getInputArguments();

        return inputArguments.contains(argument);
    }

    public void forceArgument() throws Exception
    {
        if (!hasTargetArgument())
        {
            // This won't work from IDEs
            if (JARUtilities.isRunningFromJARFile())
            {
                // Supply the desired argument
                restartApplication();
            } else
            {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Please supply the VM argument with your IDE: " + argument);
            }
        }
    }

    private void restartApplication() throws Exception
    {
        String javaBinary = getJavaBinaryPath();
        ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add(javaBinary);
        command.add("-jar");
        command.add(argument);
        String currentJARFilePath = JARUtilities.getCurrentJARFilePath();
        command.add(currentJARFilePath);

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        processBuilder.start();

        // Kill the current process
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private String getJavaBinaryPath()
    {
        return System.getProperty("java.home")
                + File.separator + "bin"
                + File.separator + "java";
    }

    public static class JARUtilities
    {
        static boolean isRunningFromJARFile() throws URISyntaxException
        {
            File currentJarFile = getCurrentJARFile();

            return currentJarFile.getName().endsWith(".jar");
        }

        static String getCurrentJARFilePath() throws URISyntaxException
        {
            File currentJarFile = getCurrentJARFile();

            return currentJarFile.getPath();
        }

        private static File getCurrentJARFile() throws URISyntaxException
        {
            return new File(JVMArgumentEnforcer.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
        }
    }
}
```

It is used as follows:

```
JVMArgumentEnforcer jvmArgumentEnforcer = new JVMArgumentEnforcer("-Duser.language=pt-BR"); // For example
jvmArgumentEnforcer.forceArgument();
```