# Add language pack to eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, plugins, localization, rcp

1. I downloaded the eclipse language pack from the following site: 
   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.10.1/indigo/indigo.php
2. I put the downloaded plugins in the plugin folder of my eclipse installation.

My question: How do I use these plugins with my eclipse RCP application now?

I seem to be unable to add them to my application because I can select them no where. I also tried to drop them into the plugin folder of my RCP application after I exported the application and adding the plugin names to the config.ini but I had no success.

I'd appreciate any help on this topic since I'm stuck :(

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem now...

Comment: If you want Eclipse to use them itself: If I remember correctly eclipse will use them automatically when you start up eclipse with the corresponding language extension. Like if you create a shortcut to the eclipse executable and add "-nl de" for german. If you need it for an exported RCP you need to specify them in your run configuration and in your product configuration.

Comment: It works for eclipse itself, and my exported RCP. But not if I try to run the RCP from eclipse...

Comment: Did you configure the run configuration that you use to start the RCP correctly? Like checking the plugins there. Make sure you dont confuse run-configuration with product-configuration.

Comment: It turned out that you have to include barbel language pack in the target platform in order to make the arguments like "-nl de" function, but there seems to be some problem since Helios

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.6 or so, Eclipse doesn't try to find additional plugins in the `plugins` folder; it will only consider what has been installed with p2 (i.e. via the "Install New Software" menu or the marketplace).

There should be a `dropins` folder next to the `plugins` folder; put the language packs in there and Eclipse should automatically pick them up.

[See the documentation for details.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins)

Comment: I tried putting the plugins in the dropin folder but it is still the same. In the runtime configuration I can't choose the new language plugins.

Comment: You can't do that at runtime, Eclipse uses the VM's default locale to see which language to use. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm how to change the default locale.