# How to customize the locale for javax validation

Tags: java, validation, locale

I've one class in java which I'm validating using javax.validation following this code:

```
    ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<ApplicationRequest>> validationErrors = validator.validate(request);

    for (ConstraintViolation<MyObject> valErrors : validationErrors) {
        errors.add(valErrors.getPropertyPath() + " " + valErrors.getMessage() + ". ");
    }
```

Now, if I execute it in an spanish server, the error messages are shown in Spanish. However, when I execute it in the testing server (which is installed in an English enviroment), the messages are shown in English. How could I tell javax validation to use the Locale for spanish language. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally solved it using a properties file for each locale, named ValidationMessages_es.properties or ValidationMessages_pt.properties, etc.

In each one of them I've customized every used message with:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=no puede ser nulo
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message=no puede estar vacío
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=debe tener entre {min} y {max} caracteres
javax.validation.constraints.Min.message=debe ser mayor que {value}
javax.validation.constraints.Past.message=debe ser una fecha pasada
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to set a specific Locale by default like this:

```
  static {
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.UK);
  }
```

In your case you should set the Locale for Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

When starting application you can set default locale:
[how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)

If you are using application server just look at the docs how to do this - usually there is configuration to do that, for instance for JBoss you need to add -Duser.language=en to the JAVA_OPTS section of run.conf.

Comment: We're using spring, so I've changed my app-config with <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="ES"/></bean>, but it doesn't make any difference. Isn't there any option to configure javax.validation directly?