# Some JSF log messages are in german for some reason

Tags: jsf, logging, locale

I'm developing a JSF application, but I'm getting some error messages in log files in german. I have no idea why is that.

Example of the messages(previous messages are in english, but the last one is not):

```
...
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger....
SEVERE: JSF kann auf Anforderung nicht den verwalteten Bean userLoginBB erstellen.  Die folgenden Probleme wurden gefunden:
 - Eigenschaft clientService für verwalteten Bean "userLoginBB ist nicht vorhanden.
 - Eigenschaft accountService für verwalteten Bean "userLoginBB ist nicht vorhanden.
```

I have only english locale in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<application>
    ...
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>en</default-locale>
    </locale-config>
    ...
</application>
```

My system locale is only english, so why is the message in german?

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I've also checked the params of running JVM:

`java.util.Locale.getDefault().toString()` =>  `en_US`
`System.getProperty("user.language")` => "en"

Comment: This question could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm

Comment: Thanks, I've checked that(see edit in OP) and I think it's ok.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Eclipse?

Comment: gordonk: Yes. Someone was setting the language on some crazy place. I dont't remember details, but I think it was something like this `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(...`. I've just deleted it and it was ok