# Play Framework float in Template with comma

Tags: scala, templates, web, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to start my Play Application in Prodmode with SSL. The Problem is, that all the floats in the templates are shown with a dot and not with comma. 
In dev mode on locahost everything is fine.... So I wonder why the floats are shown diffent in prod mode.
For the format I tried:

> @{"%.2f".format(session.get("product."+product.id.toString).toFloat*product.vkBrutto)}

and

> @String.format("%.2f",product.vkBrutto)

both ways show the wron format when I start the server in prodmode with ssl.

Answer (score 1):

I guess JVM locale differ, which impacts all Java formatting (date, number, ...). You could either enforce JVM global locale (setting system property), or using a NumberFormat inited explicitly with Locale instance (e.g. Locale.FRANCE ).

Comment: Default Play JVM locale can be set passing system properties to Play run script ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm ).