# Spring 3 different input binding on tomcat 7 and tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have got simple form (this is the renderend form with values)

```
  <form> 
     <input id="addrId"  type="hidden" value="1,173"/>
   </form>
```

backed by object like this

```
public class FormObject {
BigDecimal addrId;

//getters and setters

}
```

On tomcat 7 (debian stable) submitting this form raises an error because Spring doesn't resolve value 1,173 as `BigDecimal` value. On Tomcat 6 and on Tomcat 8 ( on different server ) this works normally.
Can I force Spring to render value without the group separator ? Or this may be caused by container or host, JDK setting?

Comment: One hint is that this might be dependend on your locale settings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm

Comment: How does `Locale` affect `BigDecimal` mapping?

Comment: thank you it was caused by locale under which tomcat was started (/etc/default/locale ). But shouldn't this be handled internally. If the form was rendered under one locale it should be resolved, binded  by the same locale that was used for rendering or not ? Or it may be problem if I am using locale interceptor which change locale  according tu user setting for each request ?