# Can I set a default for spring:message?

Tags: spring

We have our spring application set up to support both English and Spanish, using `<spring:message code="something"/>`, with all of the values stored in a database table as opposed to in a messages.properties.

This works fine, except when there doesn't happen to be a value in the database for a specific code for the given language. When that happens, the text that's displayed is the code.

We would like to default to the English text if it can't find the Spanish one. Is there a way to do this with the spring framework?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.  Just add a text field.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.1.5/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html

> Text
>
> Default text to output when a message for the given code could not be found. If both text and code are not set, the tag will output null.

Comment: But if I did that, I would end up duplicating the entire English list. That doesn't sound like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable defaulting to a locale with a combination of configurations. For instance the following could be a starting point:

- the message source must be configured with `useCodeAsDefaultMessage` as `false`;
- you must [set the Default locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm) to English;
- `fallbackToSystemLocale` must be set to `true`.