# Client to server date not correct

Tags: jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I use spring rest and jackson 2.6.1

I have a url like

So from the client this url (with startDate=13/10/2015)
/rest/appointments?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/appointments", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<AppointmentInformationDto> getAllAppointmentsFromDate(@RequestParam(value = "startDate")  Date startDate) {
        ...
}
```

Date i receive is 2016 january 10.
Not really the same date entered.

Comment: The server is likely configured to assume `MM/DD/YYYY`, reading it as the 10th day of the 13th month of 2015 (rolling over to January 2016). Possibly of interest: [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)

Comment: i prefer a solution with a converter if it's possible