# the wso2 api management is running in my machine,but there has some errors below

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

```
2016-10-24 09:24:51,216 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,217 [-] [pool-48-thread-6] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:19:13 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,218 [-] [pool-48-thread-6] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,217 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,221 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,222 [-] [pool-48-thread-6] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,222 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,223 [-] [pool-48-thread-6] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,225 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,226 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 15:17:23 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,227 [-] [pool-48-thread-6] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 14:55:32 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,228 [-] [pool-48-thread-6] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 14:48:19 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,230 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 14:55:32 CST 2016"
2016-10-24 09:24:51,231 [-] [pool-48-thread-10] ERROR SolrClient Error when passing date to create solr date format.java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Oct 20 14:46:57 CST 2016"
```

Comment: anyone is here?    please help me  thank you in advance

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please rather help. I believe it's a bug in WSO2API assuming specific locale (date.toString() format). But so far you may ignore it (for most of the use cases). And - do not push for an answer. This is community, tt may take days until you get one which is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

This is an know issue, reported [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/REGISTRY-2977). As a workaround, you can set your system locale to English.

Comment: could i fix it by setting config file?

Comment: @MrAzarenka, Yes, please check [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809137/515034)

Comment: @MrAzarenka, Accept it as the answer.