# oracle error: not a valid month

Tags: oracle

I am running an application on websphere 7.0 version which was newly setup at my QA env and getting below oracle error

```
SELECT MODIFIED_DATE 
FROM /*Query Builder Clause*/ abc 
WHERE  abc_CID = '1189' 
   AND NVL(to_date('2010-3-17 11.30.10.0', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), SYSDATE)=decode(MODIFIED_DATE,null,SYSDATE,MODIFIED_DATE)
```

throws below exception

**Error report:**

> SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
>   01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

This exception pop up only with websphere. Also, i can't modify the code since same code is running on websphere at onsite. I tried to do websphere user.timezone setting as well, also i tried default ojdbc6.jar to higher version.Also same code works fine in jboss and weblogic. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: NVL(to_date('03-17-2010 11:30:10', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),SYSDATE)

Comment: This is server generated date format with timestamp

Comment: see my answer below (for better formatting)

Comment: The format model (the second argument to the TO_DATE function) needs to *match* the actual format of the first argument.  (The value `'2010-...'` doesn't match the format model  `'MM-...'`)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not store date type with milliseconds, which means you'll have to trim the last token. In such case your expression is:

```
NVL(to_date('2010-3-17 11.30.00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24.mi.ss'),SYSDATE)
```

You can also convert to a timestamp instead:

```
NVL(to_timestamp('2010-3-17 11.30.00.0', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24.mi.ss.ff1'),SYSDATE)
```

Comment: I can't change the code, since same code is behaving well with websphere production env and other server. And we follow below for NVL(to_date('**11-30-17 11.30.10.0**', 'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') format. This is something websphere setting issue.

Comment: Should be better `NVL(to_timestamp('2010-3-17 11.30.00.0', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24.mi.ss.ff1'),SYSTIMESTAMP)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `'2010-3-17 11.30.10.0'` and `'MM-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'` don't match.  I assume the other servers where this is working are in a different locale that uses the format `MM-dd-yyyy`.  If you can't make any code changes to reformat the date you will need to change your jvm locale to match where it is working (or any locale that uses `MM-dd-yyyy`).  See the below link for changing the jvm locale:

[how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)