# PySpark Value Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm building a recommendation engine based Apache Spark. I can load data from PostgreSQL, but when I try to map this data I get a value error:

This works successfully.

```py
df = sql_context.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url=db_url,
    dbtable=db_table, driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
).load()
```

This line prints the schema to the console.

```py
df.printSchema()
```

It outputs "ınteger" instead of "integer". I think that's the issue.

Here is the console output of the schema:

```
root
 |-- id: ınteger (nullable = false)
 |-- user_id: ınteger (nullable = false)
 |-- star: ınteger (nullable = false)
 |-- product_id: ınteger (nullable = false)
```

I'm trying to get specific columns, but it raises a value error.

```py
validation_for_predict_rdd = validation_rdd.map(
    lambda x: (x.user_id, x.product_id)
)
```

Error output:

```
raise ValueError("Could not parse datatype: %s" % json_value)
ValueError: Could not parse datatype: ınteger
```

I tried to define a custom schema to solve that. But JDBC doesn't allow to use custom schema.

```py
custom_schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", LongType(), False),
    StructField("user_id", LongType(), False),
    StructField("star", LongType(), False),
    StructField("product_id", LongType(), False)])

df = sql_context.read.format('jdbc').options(
    url=db_url,
    dbtable=db_table, driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
).load(schema=custom_schema)
```

Error output:

```
raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'jdbc does not allow user-specified schemas.;'
```

What is the solution for the "ınteger" value error? I could change the database field types, but that wouldn't be a proper solution.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using `pgsql` and do `DESCRIBE TABLE`? I suspect it may be something with encoding of the database or table.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE buyexpress_service_layer
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'Turkish_Turkey.1254'
       LC_CTYPE = 'Turkish_Turkey.1254'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

Comment: Ah! `LC_` are messing with your Spark application (!) Can you change it using `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` before starting your `pyspark` or `spark-submit`?

Comment: I really hoped that it'd work, but it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the system language, but it didn't work. Furthermore, I backed up my database and created a new one. According to Jacek's answer, I used different Character type and collation. In this case, the new create statement should be like that:

```
CREATE DATABASE buyexpress_service_layer
  WITH OWNER = postgres
       TEMPLATE = template0
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

It's working now. Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 3):

The source of the problem is JVM locale. In the `local` mode, with Python interpreter locale set to `('en_US', 'UTF-8')`, you can reproduce the general issue as follows:

- Create a session:

  ```py
  from pyspark import SparkContext
  from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

  sc = SparkContext(master="local[*]")
  spark = SparkSession(sc)
  ```
- Set locale to `tr_TR`:

  ```py
  locale = sc._jvm.java.util.Locale
  locale.setDefault(locale.forLanguageTag("tr-TR"))
  ```
- Try to create a `DataFrame`:

  ```py
  spark.createDataFrame([1, 2, 3], IntegerType())
  ```

  ```
  Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.applySchemaToPythonRDD.
  : java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: integer
      at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
      at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
  ```

  Furthermore:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql.functions import col

  spark.read.json(
      sc.parallelize(["""{"x": 1}"""
  ])).selectExpr("CAST(x AS integer)")
  ```

  ```
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  ...
  ValueError: Could not parse datatype: ınteger
  ```

The simplest fix is to set `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` to [set JVM locale](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809098/6910411) to `en_US`:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

in `SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. It is probably a good idea to use the same setting for `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` as well.

You could also try using `java.util.Locale.setDefault` trick as above, before you execute any other code:

```py
locale.setDefault(locale.forLanguageTag("en-US"))
```

but I don't think it is a reliable solution.

You can also update to the recent master where this issue has been partially resolved:

- [SPARK-20156](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20156) - *Java String toLowerCase "Turkish locale bug" causes Spark problems*

More about the source of the problem: [The infamous Turkish locale bug](http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug).