# How to set the default locale for JVM running on Windows?

Tags: java, jvm, locale

I need to set the default Locale for my JVM to specific language and country.
Is it possible to set language and country on JVM level?

It was discussed in a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm), but neither changing the system-wide language nor command line arguments nor Java application modification are optimal solutions for me.

The best would be to be able to set that on particular JVM/JRE environment.

What are details behind:

> ... the JVM determines the default locale from the host environment. The host environment's locale is determined by the host operating system and the user preferences established on that system.

? What that means for JVM running on Windows?

Comment: JDK on Windows uses [`GetUserDefaultUILanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137(v=vs.85).aspx) API to determine the default Locale.

Comment: You may create .bat file to launch Java with the specified `user.language` property.