# Output and preg to Unicode Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, unicode

I have normal String property inside an object, containing accented characters.
If I debug the software (with Netbeans), into the variables panel I will see that string in the right way:

[image: variables window in debug mode]

But when I'm going to print out the variable with System.out.println I will see strange things:

[image: output window]

As you can see every "à" become "a'" and so on, and this will lead to a wrong character count, even in Matcher on the string.

How I can fix this? I need the accented characters, to have the right characters count and to use the matcher on it.
I tried many ways but is not going to work, for sure I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

[image: Full output window view]

**EDIT AGAIN**

This is the code:

```
public class TextLine {
    public List<TextPosition> textPositions = null;
    public String text = "";
}

public class myStripper extends PDFTextStripper {

    public ArrayList<TextLine> lines = null;

    boolean startOfLine = true;

    public myStripper() throws IOException
    {
    }

    private void newLine() {
        startOfLine = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void startPage(PDPage page) throws IOException
    {
        newLine();
        super.startPage(page);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeLineSeparator() throws IOException
    {
        newLine();
        super.writeLineSeparator();
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(PDDocument doc) throws IOException
    {
        lines = new ArrayList<TextLine>();
        return super.getText(doc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeWordSeparator() throws IOException
    {
            TextLine tmpline = null;

            tmpline = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
            tmpline.text += getWordSeparator();
            tmpline.textPositions.add(null);

        super.writeWordSeparator();
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
    {
        TextLine tmpline = null;

        if (startOfLine) {
            tmpline = new TextLine();
            tmpline.text = text;
            tmpline.textPositions = textPositions;
            lines.add(tmpline);
        } else {
            tmpline = lines.get(lines.size() - 1);
            tmpline.text += text;
            tmpline.textPositions.addAll(textPositions);
        }

        if (startOfLine) {
            startOfLine = false;
        }

        super.writeString(text, textPositions);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just a display issue in your console? The string still should contain the right chars.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)

Comment: No, because even if i do a string.length the count is wrong (is counting the extra accent)

Comment: can you show input and output ?

Comment: System.out will use the operating system encoding. By the way `à` could be one char or two chars: `a` + zero-width combining diacritical mark (accent). Output to a file with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Is not only about System out, is even about String.length. I've changed the post with full view. The correct characters count is 65, not 67

Comment: @SamueleDiella What's your default encoding? And how do you set the string property? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Ok just checked everything:


   `samuele@samuele-Inspiron-7737:~$ locale charmap
    UTF-8

    samuele@samuele-Inspiron-7737:~$ echo $LANG
    it_IT.UTF-8`


i'm preparing the code

Comment: i posted the code. @JoopEggen there is not a way to disable such behaviour?

Comment: @Colonder i don't think is a duplicate, i tryed to set the locales, but still the characters are wrong (characters count too)

`System.out.printf("%s %s", Charset.defaultCharset(), Locale.getDefault());
` -> output is `UTF-8 it_IT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is about the representation of certain Unicode characters.

**What is a character?** That question is hard to answer. Is `à` one character, or two (the `a` and `` ` `` on top of eachother)? It depends what you consider to be a character.

The accent graves (`` ` ``) you are seeing are actually [combining diacritical marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_Diacritical_Marks). Combining diacritical marks are separate Unicode characters, but are combined with the previous character by many text processors. For instance, `java.text.Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFC)` does such a job for you.

The library you are using (Apache PDFBox) possibly normalizes the text, so diacritics are combined with the preceding character. So in your text, some `TextPosition` instances contain two code points (more precisely, `` e` `` and `` a` ``). So the length of the list with `TextPosition` instances is 65.

However, your `String`, which is in fact a `CharSequence`, holds 67 characters, because the diacritic itself takes up 1 `char`.

`System.out.println()` just prints each character of the string, and that is represented as "dere che Geova e` il Creatore e Colui che da` la vita. Probabilmen-"

---

> Then why is the Netbeans debugger showing `"dere che Geova è il Creatore e Colui che dà la vita. Probabilmen-"` as value of the string?

That is simply because the Netbeans debugger displays the normalized text for you.

Comment: The java.**text**.Normalizer can be used for both Composing and Decomposing accented letters, that can be a single combined letter, or basic latin letter plus zero-width accents. Probably the string was in decomposed form, and System.out substituted zero-width accents by real accents or suchl. Hence this is probably the solution.

Comment: very nice, thanks a lot, this is the solution!! You saved my journey ;-)
Thanks to everyone who helped, a lot!