# How to apply font from ControlsFX Font Selector to a label?

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making app using JavaFX and Scene Builder

I have label:

```
@FXML
private Label category1;
```

When I click on toggle button it calls the method:

```
@FXML
void changeFont(ActionEvent event) {
try {
  FontSelectorDialog fs = new FontSelectorDialog(null);
  fs.setTitle("Select Font");
  fs.setHeaderText("");
  fs.setContentText("asdasdada");
  fs.show();

} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("can't load new window");
}

}
```

It shows ControlFX FontSelector Dialog where I can pick font family, font style and font size, 
There are also two buttons "OK" and "CANCEL"

How to apply changes in this dialog to my label when I click on "OK" button?

**EDIT:**

I've tried that line  in code with "en" and "US", but nothing happens.

```
FontSelectorDialog fs = new FontSelectorDialog(null);
      fs.setTitle("Select Font");
      fs.setHeaderText("");
      Localization.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));
      fs.show();
      fs.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
        if (fs.getResult() != null) {
          category1.setFont(fs.getResult());
        }
      });

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("can't load new window");
    }
```

But language doesn't change. I also found files with languages and I wanted to edit file with russian laguage there

[image: Languages]

Other languages have strings like that:

[image: DEutch language]

But russian language have strange symbols:

[image: Russian language]

I don't know how  to change those symbols to make sample text become in english.
Any ideas?

**EDIT 2:** I' tried your version and nothing happens. I even tried to use Localization in Main class, no results

```
Locale locale = Localization.getLocale();
      Localization.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US")); // en-US
      FontSelectorDialog fs = new FontSelectorDialog(null);
      fs.show();
      fs.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
        if (fs.getResult() != null) {
          category1.setStyle(null);
          category1.setFont(fs.getResult());
        }
        Localization.setLocale(locale); // Reset locale
      });
```

I copied file controlsfx.properties, changed the name to controlsfx_en_US.properties

but when I pasted this file to directory with other files alert dialog appears, even there is no such file with that name:

[image: EN US]

I' also tried to change the name to 
controlsfx_eng_USA.properties, but Alert dialog appears : "File couldn't be created"

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` doesn't wait for a user response and you have to poll the `result` property to get the result, e.g. on closing the font-dialog:

```
fs.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
    if (fs.getResult() != null) {
        category1.setFont(fs.getResult());
    }
});
```

If you want to wait for the user response (and I assume that's what you want) you can rather use `showAndWait`. For this, just replace

```
fs.show();
```

with

```
Optional<Font> optional = fs.showAndWait();
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    category1.setFont(optional.get());
}
```

See [showAndWait](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#showAndWait()) and [show](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#show()) for further details.

**EDIT 1:** Concerning the answer "EDIT: @Topaco I've tried your code"

There seems to be a problem due to the `css`, more precisely with the line `-fx-font-size: 2em;`. The problem is not directly related to the font-dialog (or the `show`- / `showAndWait`-method) itself, also a simple 
`category1.setFont(...)` doesn't work in combination with the `css` for some reason.

A solution depends on your code. If you have set the `styleClass`-property of the label in your `fxml`, a possible solution is to define the font-size **outside** of the `css` using the `style`-property:

```
<Label fx:id="category1" ... styleClass="category-label" style="-fx-font-size: 2em;"/>
```

with

```
.category-label {
    -fx-background-color: #8CA5FF;
    -fx-text-fill: #fff;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

Then, before you set the font remove the style with `category1.setStyle(null)`:

```
fs.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
    if (fs.getResult() != null) {
        category1.setStyle(null);
        category1.setFont(fs.getResult());
    }
});
```

This should work.

**EDIT 2:** Concerning the answer "EDIT: Thanx @Topaco for the Answer, it works! But I would like also to modify another thing"

The language displayed in the ControlsFX-elements is controlled by the locale returned by `Localization.getLocale()`. If no locale has been explicitly set with `Localization.setLocale(...)` the default-locale returned by `Locale.getDefault()` is used (e.g. see [ControlsFX Dialogs](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs) and [Localization](https://github.com/jinghai/controlsfx/blob/master/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/i18n/Localization.java). Generally, the latter is determined by the JVM from the host-system (e.g. see [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm)).

Thus, I assume that your default-locale is the russian-locale which is automatically taken because you haven't probably set a locale with `Localization.setLocale(...)`.

A possible solution is to set the locale at the very beginning of the `start`-method with

```
Localization.setLocale(new Locale("en","US"));
```

affecting the language of all ControlsFX-elements to be US-english.

If only the language of the font-dialog should be changed set the locale at the very beginning of the `changeFont`-method and reset it to the old value at the end:

```
@FXML
void changeFont(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Locale locale = Localization.getLocale(); 
        Localization.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US")); 
        FontSelectorDialog fs = new FontSelectorDialog(null);
        fs.show();
        fs.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            if (fs.getResult() != null) {
                category1.setStyle(null);
                category1.setFont(fs.getResult());
            }
            Localization.setLocale(locale); // Reset locale
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("can't load new window");
    }
}
```

Of course, there are further possibilities, e.g. you can change the settings in your host-system (which of course has a massive impact also outside of your application and most likely you don't really want that) or an application-wide change of the default-locale at the beginning of the `start`-method with `Locale.setDefault(...)` (which affects all elements and not only the ControlsFX-elements).

**EDIT 3:** Concerning the EDIT-section of the question

1) There are two minor problems. First, contrary to the statement in the previous EDIT-section the en-US-locale has to be set with

```
Localization.setLocale(new Locale("", ""));
```

as explained in more detail below. Second, you have to call that method **before** you create the `FontSelectorDialog`-instance i.e. at the **very beginning** of the `changeFont`-method, e.g.:

```
@FXML
void changeFont(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        Locale locale = Localization.getLocale(); 
        Localization.setLocale(new Locale("", "")); // en-US
        FontSelectorDialog fs = new FontSelectorDialog(null);
        fs.show();
        fs.setOnCloseRequest(e->{
            if (fs.getResult() != null) {
                category1.setStyle(null);
                category1.setFont(fs.getResult());
            }
            Localization.setLocale(locale); // Reset locale
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("can't load new window");
    }
}
```

That code only changes the language of the font-dialog. As an alternative there is nothing wrong with calling the `Localization.setLocale(...)` at the **very beginning** of the `start`-method which changes the language of the ControlsFX-elements in the entire application.

The `Localization.setLocale(...)`-method is also described in [ControlsFX Dialogs](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/), section "Localizing the Dialogs", point 5.

There is nothing else to do here to make it work, **in particular it isn't necessary to replace the russian text in the `controlsfx_ru_RU.properties`-file with an english text**. On the contrary, that's the completely wrong way, see below.

2) Concerning your properties-files: This is **exactly** the source from which the language information is read, i.e. if you e.g. set the locale to the russian locale with `Localization.setLocale(...)` the information is read from `controlsfx_ru_RU.properties`.

In this context, please note, that the both suffixes in the name of the properties-file, e.g. `controlsfx_ru_RU.properties`, "ru" and "RU", repectively, are used to instantiate the `Locale` which is set with the `Localization.setLocale(...)`-method. Thus, the russian locale is set with

```
Localization.setLocale(new Locale("ru", "RU"));
```

en-US is the default language which is read from `controlsfx.properties`. Thus, the en-US-locale is set with

```
Localization.setLocale(new Locale("", ""));
```

and **not** with `Localization.setLocale(new Locale("en", "US"));` as one might expect at first glance.

In general, you do not have to change the properties-files - with the only exception that you want to replace the original text with a custom text. To achieve this you have to proceed as follows: Copy the properties-file, then, make your changes in the copy and finally, place the copy in the project's src-folder. Now, the copy (with the custom text) is used instead of the original properties-file.
This is also described in [ControlsFX Dialogs](https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-dialogs/), section "Localizing the Dialogs", points 1 - 4.

*Note*: As you see each properties-file corresponds to a specific language defined by the suffixes in the name of the properties-file. The usage of a language other than specified in the name isn't intended. I mention that explicitly because you indicate in the edited question to substitute the russian text in the russian properties-file with an *english* text. **Don't do that (neither in the original properties-file nor in a copy)!** That's just confusing and it isn't necessary at all (as described above).

3) Concerning the "strange symbols": Those symbols are [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)-codepoints defining cyrillic letters, e.g. `\u041F` is the codepoint defining the cyrillic capital letter `PE`, see [Cyrillic script in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script_in_Unicode). So if you e.g. want to replace the current russian text in the `controlsfx_ru_RU.properties`-file with a new russian text you have to use the unicode-codepoints which correponds to the letters of your new russian text.