# What exactly does Locale.getDefault() retrieve?

Tags: java, java-8, windows-10, locale

I am testing language settings with an application running on Java 8. Specifically I am interested in locale settings.

Currently a test for Spanish is required. Since I use Windows 10 I did the following:

- Under `Control Panel > Region` I set all settings to Spanish, including the system configuration, without checking the box to use UTF-8 encode for compatibility
- In Win10 settings I set the UI language to Spanish and signed out, then signed back, so that my Win10 UI is now in Spanish.
- The region in those same settings is also set to Spanish
- The keyboard layout, that can be selected in the task bar, is also set to `ESP`.
- After doing all that I also restarted my system.

Everything that I was able to find via non-registry system configuration is now set to Spanish. Yet the Java call `Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()` reliably continues to deliver `en`.

Where does it get that from? Do I have to read system properties to retrieve the information, that my system runs in fact in Spanish? What is `Locale.getDefault()` even for then?

Comment: Have you checked the origin of the default locale described in the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm ?

Comment: `Locale::setDefault` may be?

Comment: I already checked `setLocale`, but there is no such call in the application. W.r.t. to @Smutje: I am aware of those properties, however with regard to the JVM - is its locale setting done only once or when first running it after booting? If the latter, then this should have been resolved by reboot I suppose.

Comment: `Locale spanish = new Locale("es", "ES");  Locale.setDefault(spanish);`

Comment: I do not want to set a default locale, I want to read the system locale and to find out what exactly `Locale.getDefault()` returns me.