# "illegal character" error when using hibernate-jpamodelgen in Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, jpamodelgen

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

When I add the above dependency and compile my project, I get an "illegal character" error for Turkish characters. My problem is same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57182568/hibernate-jpa-2-metamodel-generator-turkish-char-problem) but I didn't understand how to solve it in Spring Boot. I tried the solutions but they didn't work.

[image: error]

I would be glad if you help.

Comment: what character did you use instead of capital i ? that 's your issue.

Comment: I used the letter i. The problem is that it changes the letter i to 'İ' instead of 'I'. The language of the operating system I use is Turkish. This is probably why the error is caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Days later I tackled the issue again and finally resolved it.
I have two different solutions for the following two different situations.

**1) Using maven wrapper (mvnw)**

- Create .mvn/jvm.config file in the project.
- Add the following options to file.

```
-Duser.language=en
-Duser.country=US
```

**2) Using Intellij Idea**

- Add the same options above to the .vmoptions file described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties).
- Select File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate and Restart