# How do I change the language of my java complier?

Tags: java, jvm

My default language is Chinese and that makes debug very hard.

I know there is a lot of similar questions here, but I have no prior knowledge of working with JVM or command line setup of java, I tried to copy their command to my terminal and that does not work at all.

Could someone just provide me a line of code that change the language of java compiler? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-for-my-jvm

Comment: *"change the language of java **compiler**"* Are you asking how to get compiler error messages in another language?

Comment: Does `javac` produce localized error messages? I don’t think so. And “debug” doesn’t imply compiler error messages anyway. So which debugger are we talking about?

Comment: @KelvinHo not really it still does not specify what to do, it may assume I have already known about setting up java through command line option, but I did not know。

Comment: @Andreas Yes, now the complier displays error message in chinese which is not so helpful.

Comment: @Holger what I mean is that currently I cannot understand the Chinese version of the error message and It makes debugging process hard in the sense I cannot even use google to google the error message.

Comment: @Tony but what error message are you talking about? A message from the compiler, as your question says, or rather a message from the JVM or even your own application?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the the default locale of the JVM by passing the following system properties:

> -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US

Comment: how may I pass this command? using terminal or what, sorry I have no idea how to set this relate to JVM.

Comment: Do you use any IDE or just run the program in the command prompt? If you just run in the command prompt, you can just run like this:
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US package.name.ClassName