# When I use printf it gives me "???"

Tags: java

**When I use printf it gives me "???"**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner kbScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            double m,c , m2 , c2;
            System.out.println("Enter the coefficients of the first line: ");
            m= kbScanner.nextDouble();
            c= kbScanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.printf("The first line equation is: y = %.1f x + %.1f  \n" , m,c );



    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:** 
Enter the coefficients of the first line:

1  2

The first line equation is: y = ??? x + ???

WHY? How can I fix it?

Comment: are you running this on a special device?

Comment: Is my Laptop a special device? No.

Comment: This should be working fine: https://ideone.com/bB6O7B

Comment: your laptop is not special, but what is the result of `Locale.getDefault()`? or try `...printf(Locale.ROOT, "The first ....` - I suspect that the default locale is one that uses digits that are not available on your console (e.g. arabic digits)

Comment: how? please ,write it as complete code then I will try it

Comment: just add `Locale.ROOT` as an additional (first) argument to the `printf` method, that is `System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT, "The first line equation is: y = %.1f x + %.1f  \n" , m,c );` - or add `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ROOT);` at the very start of the main method

Comment: Locale cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: really, have you tried to `import` it ? eclipse should help you with that (or  add `import java.util.Locale;` to the other import)

Comment: the same way you did with `Scanner`!

Comment: Yes!! Finally. it gives the exact value!! How can I fix the default locale as you call it?

Comment: "as I call it"? well, it is what it is (and also how *Java* calls it)....since you are using Eclipse (as commented somewhere else) try setting your workspace, in Eclipse, to UTF-8 (Window - Preferences - General - Workspace - Text file encoding)

Comment: Now it gives me Arabic numbers! I want English numbers.

Comment: hey?! help me please

Comment: maybe *use* a special device (set to a language that uses that digits); or set the so called - not only by me - "default locale"; or search the net like [how do I set the default locale for my JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809098/85421); or even do not use `printf`

Comment: my default text file encoding is Cp1256! How to add the Cp1252?

Comment: you german guy, Thank You! may god bless you. The problem is coming from my device. Do I have to use those functions all the time?

Comment: you must see what better suits you (eventually including some of the options from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8809098/85421) I posted in last comment): not use `printf`; use `Locale.ROOT` (or different one) in `printf` (where needed); `Locale.setDefault()` (for whole program); start java using `-Duser.language`; setting `JAVA_OPTIONS` to use  `-Duser.language`; or even (try) changing the language of the system (not sure if that is acceptable/desirable, can mess up other applications)

Answer (score 0):

What are m2 and c2 for? 
Just set them to `.1*m` and `.1*c` respectively in your code, then set your formatting specifiers to `%f`.

Your class will look something like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner kbScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            double m,c , m2 , c2;
            System.out.println("Enter the coefficients of the first line: ");
            m= kbScanner.nextDouble();
            c= kbScanner.nextDouble();
            m2= .1 * m;
            c2= .1 * c;
            System.out.printf("The first line equation is: y = %f x + %f" , m,c );
```

I think that should solve the issue. Good luck.

Comment: these are for  the sec line

Comment: Please suggest another platform than eclipse