# Java String decoding differs between IDE and runnable JAR

Tags: java, string, intellij-idea, character-encoding

In my program I encrypt a string and decrypt it again. When I run it in IntelliJ, it works fine, but when I build a jar, some characters don´t decrypt correctly. E.g. "ä" becomes "Ã¤". I learned that happens when text is encoded as UTF-8 and decoded as ISO 8859-1. (But my file is encoded as UTF-8 already)

Can anybody explain why there is a difference in encryption/decoding between running the program in IntelliJ and running it as a jar?

```
package main;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec password = createKey("safePassword");

        String message = "hello ä ö ü ß";

        String encryptedMessage = encrypt(message, password);
        //this output is the same in IntelliJ and as a jar
        System.out.println(encryptedMessage);

        byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt(encryptedMessage, password);
        //this output gets messed up when I run it as a jar but not in Intellij
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedBytes));
        //this output works both ways
        System.out.println(new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    public static String encrypt(String message, SecretKeySpec key) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(String encryptedMessage, SecretKeySpec key) throws Exception {
        byte[] message = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedMessage);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(message);
    }

    public static SecretKeySpec createKey(String key) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        keyBytes = sha.digest(keyBytes);
        keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16);
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    }

}
```

Output in IntelliJ:

```
8nno4HGKG4/Ni/Sxun+s3roOAaav+eXT4kd0ivgZFBA=
hello ä ö ü ß
hello ä ö ü ß
```

Output from jar:

```
8nno4HGKG4/Ni/Sxun+s3roOAaav+eXT4kd0ivgZFBA=
hello Ã¤ Ã¶ Ã¼ Ã?
hello ä ö ü ß
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.println(new String(decryptedBytes));
```

Your 'bytes' are a UTF-8 representation.

The above line constructs a string interpreting the bytes using the platform standard charset, which is not necessarily UTF-8.

Therefore the resulting string is garbage.

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte%5B%5D))

Comment: I understand, that makes sense. Thank you.
Nevertheless, that doesn´t explain the difference between running it in IntelliJ and as a jar. Why would they use different standard charsets?

Comment: It's under user control. I use Linux; my standard locale is UTF-8.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-in-the-jvm)

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely on the default character set like you're doing with `new String(decryptedBytes)`. The problem is that depending on the OS, and the exact way Java is started, your application may use a different default character set. In other words, you should *always* use `String.getBytes(Charset charset)` or `String.getBytes(String charsetName)`, and `new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` or `new String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName)`.

On Windows, some ways of launching a Java application will default to a simple single-byte character set, and some other ways default to UTF-8. For example, on my machine, it will default to Cp1252 (windows-1252) in some situations (e.g. using java -jar from the command prompt with Java 8, while using java -jar with Java 16 will use UTF-8). However, the way IntelliJ launches Java will make it default to UTF-8 even when using Java 8. Similar things apply for Linux, though there it is more common that the default locale uses UTF-8.