# tomcat 9 changes decimal format

Tags: tomcat, decimalformat

When I upgrade my application server from tomcat 7 to 9, default decimal format is changed.

For example,

```
new DecimalFormat(".##").format(111.111)
```

Its result in tomcat 7 is "111.11" but in tomcat 9 result is "111,11"

I can accomplish the problem adding locale setting in code like below

```
Locale locale=new Locale("en","US");
String pattern=".##";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat=(DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
decimalFormat.applyPattern(pattern);
```

But how can I accomplish decimal format locale settings without changing the application code? Is there a way to change locale from tomcat  or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default locale in the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809098/how-do-i-set-the-default-locale-in-the-jvm)

Comment: Tomcat does not change the default locale. My guess you try to change it in your code by setting the `user.language` system property, which works only until the first usage of the `Locale` class.