# Why I am getting en_US as default locale?

Tags: java, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java 7 default locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107972/java-7-default-locale)

When I am printing `Locale.getDefault()` I am getting `en_US`.

On my system I have set timezone as `(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna`.

In 'control panel -> Region and Language', Region is `Italian(Italy)`.

Why I am getting locale as en_US?

Comment: restart the machine and then try.

Comment: It is "Locale". I have edited your question.

Comment: If you are using Java 7, you can set the default locale. How the JVM determines the default locale is otherwise dependent on the underlying system