# Tomcat ignores Accept-Language header

Tags: java, tomcat

In my Java application, I set the default system locale (`Locale.getDefault()`) as Accept-Language header for the HTTP request to my tomcat web application.
In my case, this is `de_DE`.

On server side, I try to get the locale by using `request.getLocale()`. But I only get an empty string.

If I set the Accept-Language to `de`, everything works fine.

Why does `de_DE` not work as Accept-Language header?

**EDIT:**

This is my client side code:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().toString());
```

And this my server side code:

```
request.getLocale().toString(); //empty string
request.getHeader("Accept-Language"); //"de_DE"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319889/1173112

Comment: This does not answer my question. The problem (in my view) is not, that Java returns a wrong location, but tomcat does not recognize de_DE in the Accept-Language header.

Comment: How do you know the problem is with Tomcat? Have you tried any other server? Can you show us some code so we can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format for language tags is de-DE. With a dash, not an underscore.

I guess it wouldn't be surprising if other webservers were more lenient and would accept de_DE to be equivalent, but Tomcat does not. For reference, Tomcat delegates this parsing to Locale.forLanguageTag(), which makes it clear that it expects format de-DE.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue. Locale.getDefault().toString().replace('_', '-');

Answer (score 0):

As kumesana pointed out, Tomcat will use `Locale.forLanguageTag()` to convert the Accept-Language header value into a Locale. There is an opposite method to convert a Locale instance into the expected header String: `toLanguageTag()`

I would suggest using this rather than manually replacing underscore with hyphen, so your code would be like the following:

`connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag());`