# How to detect user's REAL regional setting (locale) in Java

Tags: java, locale, java-7

**UPDATE:**
Putting a working/fixed code here just for the sake of completeness.
Detailed explanation of why this is happening can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8319889/1122039)**.
Thanks to user *Perception* for pointing me to it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Demonstrating proper usage of Java's {@linkplain Locale} class
 * in respect to accessing user's regional settings, specifically
 * the locale configured for date/time/number formatting.
 *
 * @see Locale#getDefault(java.util.Locale.Category)
 * @see Locale#getDefault()
 */
public class DefaultLocaleChangesJava7Demo {
  private static final String NO_VALUE = "<- empty ->";
  private static final String[] ENVVAR_NAMES = {
      "java.runtime.name", "java.runtime.version", "java.vm.name", "java.vm.version",
      "os.name", "os.version", "os.arch",
      "user.language", "user.country", "user.script", "user.variant",
      "user.language.format", "user.country.format", "user.script.format" };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print out select environment variables.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("System Information (environment):");
    for (String name : ENVVAR_NAMES) {
      String value = System.getProperty(name);
      if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
        value = NO_VALUE;
      }
      System.out.println("  " + name + " = " + value);
    }

    // Print out default display locale information.
    System.out.println("\nDefault Display Locale:");
    final Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println(localeToString(defaultLocale, "  default."));

    // Print out default format locale information.
    System.out.println("\nDefault Format Locale:");
    final Locale formatLocale = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
    System.out.println(localeToString(formatLocale, "  format."));
  }

  public static String localeToString(Locale locale, String prefix) {
    final StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    result.append(prefix);
    result.append("locale.language = ");
    result.append(locale.getLanguage());
    result.append(" (");
    result.append(locale.getDisplayLanguage());
    result.append(")\n");

    result.append(prefix);
    result.append("locale.country = ");
    result.append(locale.getCountry());
    result.append(" (");
    result.append(locale.getDisplayCountry());
    result.append(")\n");

    result.append(prefix);
    result.append("locale.script = ");
    result.append(locale.getScript());
    result.append(" (");
    result.append(locale.getDisplayScript());
    result.append(")\n");

    result.append(prefix);
    result.append("locale.variant = ");
    result.append(locale.getVariant());
    result.append(" (");
    result.append(locale.getDisplayVariant());
    result.append(")\n");

    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

## Original Question

Today I noticed that Java's `Locale.getDefault()` is not returning the regional settings I configured in my Windows 7 account.

Demo application:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class BadLocaleDemo {
  private static final String NO_VALUE = "<- empty ->";
  private static final String[] ENVVAR_NAMES = {
      "java.runtime.name", "java.runtime.version", "java.vm.name", "java.vm.version",
      "os.name", "os.version", "os.arch" };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print out select environment variables.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("System Information (environment):");
    for (String name : ENVVAR_NAMES) {
      String value = System.getProperty(name);
      if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
        value = NO_VALUE;
      }
      System.out.println("  " + name + " = " + value);
    }

    // Print out default locale information.
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Default Locale:");

    final Locale defaultLocale = Locale.getDefault();
    System.out.println("  default.locale.language = " + defaultLocale.getLanguage());
    System.out.println("  default.locale.country = " + defaultLocale.getCountry());
    System.out.println("  default.locale.display.language = " + defaultLocale.getDisplayLanguage());
    System.out.println("  default.locale.display.country = " + defaultLocale.getDisplayCountry());
  }
}
```

And the information it prints out:

```
System Information (environment):
  java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
  java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_02-b13
  java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
  java.vm.version = 22.0-b10
  os.name = Windows 7
  os.version = 6.1
  os.arch = amd64

Default Locale:
  default.locale.language = en
  default.locale.country = US
  default.locale.display.language = English
  default.locale.display.country = United States
```

Default local should be `sr_RS` as per my regional settings (names of week days are in cyrilic on the tray clock), but Java is reporting `en_US`.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Only relevant posts I found on StackOverflow are these two:

- [How to detect operating system language (locale) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469435/how-to-detect-operating-system-language-locale-from-java-code)
- [List of useful environment settings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585699/list-of-useful-environment-settings-in-java)

Comment: @Perception Thanks, that wasn't in the search results. Good and fast catch.