# Oracle SQL Developer client encoding

Tags: windows, oracle, plsql, character-encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

I read many of the related Stack Overflow's topics and I spent a whole day with googleing the following problem but I haven't found anything that would help, however the problem not seems to be complicated.

I have an Oracle database.
Let's see the following PL/SQL script:

```sql
    CREATE TABLE Dummy(
       id number(19,0),
       tclob clob,
       tnclob nclob,
       PRIMARY KEY (id));
    
    INSERT INTO dummy (id, tclob, tnclob) VALUES (1, 'ñ$ß¤*>;''<’', 'ñ$ß¤*>;''<’');
    SELECT tclob, tnclob FROM dummy;
```

My problem is that 'ñ' and '’' characters are stored as a question mark.
I also tried to load the previously inserted values through JAVA, but I get the question marks instead of the special characters.

I created a small Java method which uses OraclePreparedStatement to save test data, and I use setNString() method to attach the nclob data to the query. In this case all characters are displayed fine in Java and also in SqlDeveloper.

So a possible solution is to use JAVA to save my data into the db. I have a thousands of lines SQL script which inserts data and I don't necessarily want to write the whole thing again in java.

So the question is: why the SqlDeveloper breaks the special characters?

My settings:

```sql
    SELECT DECODE(parameter, 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'CHARACTER SET',
    'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'LANGUAGE',
    'NLS_TERRITORY', 'TERRITORY') name,
    value from v$nls_parameters
    WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY')
```

Result:

```
+---------------+--------------+
|     NAME      |    VALUE     |
+---------------+--------------+
| LANGUAGE      | HUNGARIAN    |
| TERRITORY     | HUNGARY      |
| CHARACTER SET | EE8ISO8859P2 |
+---------------+--------------+
```

I changed `SqlDeveloper/Preferences/Environment/Encoding` to `UTF-8`.
I also changed `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDb11g_home1` value to `HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY.UTF8`

**Update:** I tried to insert the data with the following syntaxes:

```
    INSERT INTO dummy (id, tclob, tnclob) VALUES (1, N'ñ$ß¤*>;''<’', N'ñ$ß¤*>;''<’');
    INSERT INTO dummy (id, tclob, tnclob) VALUES (1, 'ñ$ß¤*>;''<’', to_nclob('ñ$ß¤*>;''<’'));
```

Nothing helped.

So what can I do?

Comment: Could you show here a result of this query: `select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%SET'`

Comment: The result of your query:                         NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET EE8ISO8859P2

Comment: Can you try to close Oracle SQL Developer, then set NLS_LANG=HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY.UTF8 in the windows environment, and open SQL Developer and try again ?

Comment: I tried - i guess you mean that i should add an environment variable to the system. Well, i tried it,but it wasn"t help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the PC that PLSQL is installed, set the value of `NLS_LANG` registery entry equal to the PC's `operation system locale (code page)`, equivalent value.
[How to detect operating system language locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469435/how-to-detect-operating-system-language-locale-from-java-code/2469609#2469609)
[How to map OS locale to NLS_LANG value?](http://docs.oracle.com/html/B13804_02/gblsupp.htm#BCEEEJGF)

When using PLSQL the initial parameter of client-language that is required to create an Oracle session is read from NLS_LANG registry entry.
[Due to Oracle documents](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#i1006330), invalid data usually occurs in a database because the NLS_LANG parameter is not set properly on the client.
The NLS_LANG value should reflect the client **operating system code page**.
For example, in an English Windows environment, the code page is WE8MSWIN1252. When the NLS_LANG parameter is set properly, the database can **automatically convert** incoming data from the client operating system to its encoding.

When using JAVA method, the client-language parameter is set by the value from the Control Panel, under Regional and Language Options, so the things will be OK.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it mean that I cannot change the encoding of the sqldeveloper to have the proper encoding?

Comment: Definitely you can. Just set the registry entry equal to your operating system local.For example if it is english-us set the value to AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252 and then restart. Let me know what happens

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow afternoon I'll try it and reply with my results.

Comment: Hi Mohsen, thanks for your help. I tried what you suggested. I checked my systeminfo and my system language local is hu. So I tried to set the NLS_LANG (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDb11g_home1) to HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY.EE8MSWIN1250, but nothing happened. Then I set that to AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252 - also nothing happened. I restarted my computer after each regedit changes. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDb11g_home1\NLS_LANG to HUNGARIAN_HUNGARY.EE8MSWIN1250 ?

Comment: Yes - but without any positive result.

Comment: In plsql click on supportInfo (i think the name is this) a page will opens that will have some information find oracle_home, that is the home plsql is using to connect, what is the value?

Comment: If I'm correct you mean sqldeveloper help/about/properties. Well, I found the oracle.home value which points to my sqldeveloper folder on the HDD. But I also found some encoding information, like file.encoding = Cp1250, sun.jnu.encoding = Cp150.

Comment: No. The value of oracle.home = c:\sqldeveloper. In the registry, the value of the ORACLE_HOME_KEY = SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraDb11g_home1, and the value of ORACLE_HOME = C:\oracle\de\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2 (I don't have the c:\oracle folder on my machine, maybe it's some garbage), and the value of the ORACLE_HOME_NAME = OraDb11g_home1

Comment: Search the garbage value in registery, probably you will find a garbage Oracle-home; Delete the registry entry of garbage Oracle-home, then re-install plsql.

Comment: You mean I should reinstall the sqldeveloper client? I do not have oracle server on my local computer.

Comment: No any oracle home represents an Oracle Client installation, first search the registry for invalid home

Comment: I found several invalid entries - I had a full Oracle Server install on my local computer, I guess when I removed it, some garbage was left in the registry and that's why it has no effect when I change it.

Comment: I deleted the registry garbage, but sqldeveloper "reinstall" was just to delete the existing sqldeveloper and I unpacked it again. But the problem still exists. Fortunately we could manage to change our database encoding to UTF-8 which I guess solves the problem. The other thing is that I successfully installed Toad to another machine and using that I didn't have any encoding problem. So I guess that's the way. Anyway, thanks for your assistance, I accept your answer because that's how encoding things can be set. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change `NLS_LANG` value on your Win PC with `regedit` tool.

Path is: `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE`, when `NLS_LANG` contain value of your Oracle client's current encoding.

There is Oracle's list of available encodings:
[Commonly Used Values for NLS_LANG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14312/gblsupp.htm#g635100)