# Running command prompt command in English

Tags: java, command-prompt

I want to run a command line programme on Windows, here is the code.

```
    public static String runcmd(String cmd) throws IOException {
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null)
            break;
        sb.append(line + "%SKIPLINE%");
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Everything work fine, except that it prints out the output in Chinese because my Windows language is set to Chinese. Is there any ways to make it output in English?

Comment: in linux it would be as easy as setting the LANG env variable for the process using `processBuilder.environment().put("LANG", "en_US.UTF-8")`

Comment: @Svetlin Zarev I use Windows, and it doesnt work on Windows D:

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469435/how-to-detect-operating-system-language-locale-from-java-code
What you want to find is a way to temporarily set your locale in the program to English.

Comment: @SandySimonton Thanks! I get it to work now.

Comment: @RandomGuy: No problem, please accept my answer when you get a chance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link: [how to detect operating system language (locale) from java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469435/how-to-detect-operating-system-language-locale-from-java-code)

What you want to find is a way to temporarily set your locale in the program to English.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`https://wandersick.blogspot.com/p/change-non-english-command-line.html`

Or
Execute

`chcp 437`
in the cmd prompt.

For example:

```
C:\Users\javaserv> chcp 437
Active code page: 437
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Its better to show some code or notes before referencing so that there would still be something to read even if the link is removed.