# Java: Covert comma separated number to number

Tags: java, format

```
NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(new Integer(1000)) // 1,000 in US locale, 1 000 in France
```

"1,000" -> 1000
"1 000" -> 1000

Are there any methods or ways to convert number-formatted number to integer in any locales?

Comment: Although ... you don't know the locale, right? But if you don't know the locale, then what is the number `1.000` for you? "1" with US local or 1000 with some european locales?

Comment: @Tom 

> Does this answer your question? How do I convert a String to Double in Java using a specific locale?

kind of... but we don't know which locale is used. Yeah that's the point I'm stuck with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in the [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class, it allows you to format based on locale, which you just need to find out to access the right one:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRENCH);

myNumber = nf.parse(<String or Number here>);
```

To get the locale, you need, [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469435/how-to-detect-operating-system-language-locale-from-java-code)